# "ubuntu-drivers devices" command do not displaying

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to install the drivers for my ***Graphic Card NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti***

To see the recommended drivers I am using the command:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

But the command does not display anything

Comment: Software & Updates > Additional Drivers

Comment: Try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Software & Updates > Additional Drivers: No additional drivers available

Comment: Try ```sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall```: No drivers found for automatic installation.

Comment: Did you check this out already? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: 2 possibly  dumb questions:  1. Do you have an active internet connection? and 2. Have you already installed updates, other software or at least run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: You have two options: If you use ubuntu 20.04 , then simply run ```sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440```.If not , download the recommended 440 driver for your GPU [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/160175/en-us) the run the following commands : ```chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.100.run ; sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.100.run```

Comment: May possibly be due to over-enthusiastic security lockdown not letting drivers be listed?

Comment: @DragonLord, what does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Software & Updates > Ubuntu software > check 'Proprietary drivers for devices' option. Then update from gui or `sudo apt update`

Comment: any CLI solution? I am running Ubuntu on WSL

Comment: Regarding WSL, I've tried it using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455` to update via CLI, but still. had no luck. I had to revert to dual booting to Ubuntu.

Comment: For WSL, there is a completely differ approach.  WSL, being hosted under windows, uses the windows driver.  CUDA can be set up to work in WSL using [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview) on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the most likely cause is that you don't have the restricted repository enabled in your /etc/apt/sources.list. All the proprietary drivers are there.