# No output on " ubuntu-drivers devices"

Tags: 18.04, drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I am trying to install Nvidia driver on my Ubuntu 18.04. 
When i check for `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`, there is no output. 
I have already checked the option for "Proprietary devices for drivers" in Software and Updates as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143062/ubuntu-drivers-devices-command-do-not-displaying?newreg=abd99fda47fe40bb8c89d4e2b7cecd74).  
The Additional Drivers tab shows :

```
No additional drivers available.
```

What am I missing ?

Output of

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
```

Comment: What's the model of your GPU? Please add it to your post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I ran lspci | grep VGA, it returned: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller.

Comment: Sorry if my question seems a little silly but are you sure you have an Nvidia GPU ? Even if you don't have the driver for that , you should be able to see the device in the output of ```lspci``` because those are the results of [SMBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) probes.It doesn't need any driver to succeed.

Comment: Okay i see, i do not have NVIDIA graphics card. so i will not be able to add drivers for it. that was so foolish of me !